# scipy.io typeerror:buffer too small for requested array

Tags: python, file-io, scipy

I have a problem in python. I'm using scipy, where i use scipy.io to load a .mat file. The .mat file was created using MATLAB.

```
listOfFiles = os.listdir(loadpathTrain)
      for f in listOfFiles:

         fullPath = loadpathTrain + '/' + f
         mat_contents = sio.loadmat(fullPath)
         print fullPath
```

Here's the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tryRankNet.py", line 1112, in <module>
    demo()
  File "tryRankNet.py", line 645, in demo
    mat_contents = sio.loadmat(fullPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 111, in loadmat
    matfile_dict = MR.get_variables()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py", line 356, in get_variables
    getter = self.matrix_getter_factory()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 602, in matrix_getter_factory
    return self._array_reader.matrix_getter_factory()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 274, in matrix_getter_factory
    tag = self.read_dtype(self.dtypes['tag_full'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py", line 171, in read_dtype
    order='F')
TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array
```

The whole thing is in a loop, and I checked the size of the file where it gives the error by loading it interactively in IDLE.

The size is (9,521), which is not at all huge. I tried to find if I'm supposed to clear the buffer after each iteration of the loop, but I could not find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of scipy are you using? I only ask because the line number in 171 doesn't match up for me. The read_dtype code doesn't start until line 249 in my version. I'm using version 0.7.1.

Comment: @Justin
Hi, synaptic package manager shows scipy version installed as 0.7.0-2

Comment: It's quite possible that this problem can be solved by upgrading to a newer version of Scipy -- 0.7.0 is over two years old now.